# tak actual offset of element which was resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The problem is I need actual offset from my element which was resized. Which means whenever I resize my element (it's simple colored bar and can be resized) and I need to read It's left offset right after resizing is finished.

When I use stop event from jquery-ui The previous position is shown.

```
$('.shop-' + shopID).resizable({
            stop: function (event, ui) {

                var leftMargin = $('.hour-6').offset().left+20;
                var currentPosition = $('.shop-1').offset().left; //when I print this previous offset is shown.
            },
            grid: grid,
            animate: true,
            handles: 'e, w'
        });
    });
```

Here is script fragment

Example started position is 50px, when I moved it to left by 20 px (so it's 30 px now) 50 px is printed. When I move it again 20px left (10px now) 30 px is printed. So It's not actual offset/possition.

I have tried using possition as well, It's work exactly the same.
Even 'resize' option shows previous offset/possition.

Answer (score 0):

I need to change two things :
1) I need to call ui possition
2) set Timeout

```
            setTimeout(function () {
                leftOffset = ui.position.left;
                rightOffset = leftOffset + ui.size.width;
                if (leftOffset < leftMargin) {
                    console.log('przekroczono');
                    //$('.shop-' + shopID).width(60);
                    console.log($('.shop-' + shopID).css('left', leftMargin +'px'));
                }

            }, 500);
```